# ROMMON and u-boot on network devices

Tags: networking, bootloader, u-boot

What is the difference between rommon and u-boot in network devices? I'm reading some device documentation and i can't quite tell what is the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Rommon is Cisco bootloader for their Router devices

while U-boot is a very generic bootloader for lots of embedded device

both U-boot and Rommon support tftp

U-boot Support `sntp nfs` while Rommon dont

Answer (score 0):

u-BOOT may not support booting of raw vmlinux image but ROMMMON(rom on monitor) has support for loading and booting the raw vmlinux image.